# Javascript, copy a text in a field by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, button

I try to make a simple javascript fonction which will allow me to click on a button, then a text is duplicated into a field.

For example:
On my HTML page (or PHP), I have a blank field, a text and a button, like:

> THE FIELD
> Hello everybody THE BUTTON

When I click on the button, the text "Hello everybody" appears in the field.

Thank you very much if you have a simple code example.

Sim100

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `.value`. Here you go:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('foo').value = 'Hello everybody'">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="mytextinput">
<br>Hey Guys <button onclick="document.getElementById('mytextinput').value='Hey Guys, thanks for clicking the button';">Click Me</button>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/sUYEk/

Comment: Thank you so much, I wanted something like that :)
Thx

Answer (score 0):

What I get from the question is that you want to place the text that comes before the button into the text field. To improve earlier answers, this can be done with the .innerText function.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function moveTextIntoInput(){
                var text = document.getElementById('text').innerText;
                document.getElementById('text-input').value = text;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text-input"><br/>
        <span id="text">Hi everyone!</span><button onclick="moveTextIntoInput()">Click Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```